# Javascript - Wikipedia API sends extract that contains weird encode

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api

This is what I get from sending a GET request to the wikipedia API

> Norway (\u00a0(\u00a0listen); Norwegian: \u00a0Norge (Bokm\u00e5l) or \u00a0Noreg (Nynorsk); Northern Sami: Norga)
>   Officially the Kingdom of Norway, is a sovereign state and unitary monarchy whose territory comprises the western portion of the Scandinavian Peninsula plus the remote island of Jan Mayen and the archipelago of Svalbard. The Antarctic Peter I Island and the sub-Antarctic Bouvet Island are dependent territories and thus not considered part of the Kingdom. Norway also lays claim to a section of Antarctica known as Queen Maud Land. Until 1814, the kingdom included the Faroe Islands, Greenland, and Iceland. It also included Bohusl\u00e4n until 1658, J\u00e4mtland and H\u00e4rjedalen until 1645, Shetland and Orkney until 1468, and the Hebrides and Isle of Man until 1266.

As you can see the return string have a lot of weird encoding here and there which resembles Unicode or something like that.

Does anybody know what this is and a way of removing it?

Comment: That should be decoded by your JSON parser. (Presumably. You failed to include a [mcve] showing how you were accessing the API)

Comment: I chose to not use the JSON part of and just split the return string after "extract":" and split before "}. I did it because one of the keys to get into the extract is the same as the pageID of the wikipedia page, and I am developing a program where the user searches for the wikipedia page, so I found it hard to use the JSON parse. @Quentin

Comment: Well, that's your problem. You found it too hard to use a library to parse JSON so you decided to write your own parser … which is **much harder** and your attempt doesn't support enough of JSON to be useful. Use a JSON parser.

Comment: So what do you suggest i do if i want to use the JSON parser?

Comment: Read its documentation. It's not complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that it's encoded, you can go here: https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ and try to have it converted where it will turn it into something like this:

`Norway ( ( listen); Norwegian:  Norge (Bokmål) or  Noreg (Nynorsk); Northern Sami: Norga), officially the Kingdom of Norway, is a sovereign state and unitary monarchy whose territory comprises the western portion of the Scandinavian Peninsula plus the remote island of Jan Mayen and the archipelago of Svalbard. The Antarctic Peter I Island and the sub-Antarctic Bouvet Island are dependent territories and thus not considered part of the Kingdom. Norway also lays claim to a section of Antarctica known as Queen Maud Land. Until 1814, the kingdom included the Faroe Islands, Greenland, and Iceland. It also included Bohuslän until 1658, Jämtland and Härjedalen until 1645, Shetland and Orkney until 1468, and the Hebrides and Isle of Man until 1266.`

Looks like you'll have to have code that can handle that.

Comment: Seems like you are right, but what encoding is it, and are there any built in decoding inside javascript?

Comment: @Quentin If you had read the documentation for the decodeURIComponent function, you would see that the it is not made for url decoding. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: Read the documentation

Comment: @HermanNeple try it in the console, that's how I was able to spit out the above.